# react-native-fbsdk-next hidden modal on android

Tags: javascript, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk-next

Calling `LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile"])`on android opens the facebook modal, then when I click on continue, the modal closes, howewer it seems like a hidden modal is still present on the screen, since only after using the manual goback gesture is it possible to interact with the app again, then only a response is returned as follow `{"isCancelled": true}`.

It seems like the interface is bugged. Any help on this issue ?

I'm using the lastest "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^11.1.0" version.

Complete code

```
LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile"]).then(
                    function(result) {
                      console.log('result', result)
                      if (result.isCancelled) {
                        console.log("Login cancelled");
                      } else {
                        console.log(
                          "Login success with permissions: " +
                            result.grantedPermissions.toString()
                        );
                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                          (data) => {
                            console.log('data', data)
                            if(data.accessToken) {
                              facebookConnect(
                                {
                                  access_token: data.accessToken,
                                },
                                dispatch,
                                navigation
                              )
                            } else {
                              console.log('data', data)
                              Alert.alert(t(trans.error_message))
                            }

                          }
                        )
                      }
                    },
                    function(error) {
                      console.log("Login fail with error: " + error);
                    }
                  );
```